# Qt4.6: QTextDocument <HR> tag prints only very thin, almost invisible hair lines

Tags: printing, qt4, qtextdocument

When printing a `QTextDocument` with `doc->print()` I almost cannot see the horizontal rules inserted by `<hr>`. When printing to PDF these are clearly visible. But when printed to a printer these lines are very very thin lines, almost invisible on the paper.

How do I fix this? I currently helped myself by inserting an `<img>` with a black pixel but this is very cumbersome as I have to exactly figure out the proper pixel width by trial and error.

Answer (score 1):

`<hr>` tag supports the width attribute, which can be specified as an absolute or relative (%) value.  E.g.:
`<hr width=3>`